# using SQL case statement to find all the values that have a 'B' then keep all the numbers in front of the 'B'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get my SQL statement to: A. see if the values in TrackingNumber column contain a 'B', B. take only the numbers in front of the 'B', C. add the COST column of the original row to the COST of the row where the value from B. = shipment number for a new row and D. delete the old row. I have no idea where to begin except that I probably need a CASE statement. Below is a sample table with the expected result. How would I go about such task? I know that "CASE when TrackingNumber = 1B4 THEN Do something" but does that work for adding and subtracting and deleting rows out of my select statement?

```
 |ShipmentNumber|COST|TrackingNumber|
 |1             |20  |154           |
 |2             |30  |1B3           |
 |3             |10  |1B4           |
 |4             |40  |567           |
```

So my new result should be

```
|ShipmentNumber|COST|TrackingNumber|
|1             |60  |154           |
|4             |40  |567           |
```

Comment: if letters can be in front of B in the tracking number, can shipment number also be a letter since you're trying to match them up?

Comment: So your question is? I don't see a question, just a list of requirements. This site is for programming questions, not a jobs board you can dump requirements and expect someone else do your job for you...

Comment: Use charindex() to find the B. Use left() to get the values before the B. Use Case to calculate a new ShipmentNumber and TrackingNumber. Use an aggregate query to combine the rows.

Comment: I don't see why you'd need a CASE statement.   If the tracking number doesn't have a B, then there would be no characters before the B, so it would get ignored without a CASE statement.

Comment: I am not wanting anyone to do my job for me. I am looking to see if this is possible and get pointed in the right direction. If I cannot get an answer then that is fine. I accept help, guidance, a shove in the right direction, etc. How am I supposed to learn if I cannot get any help from anyone, ever? I have edited my post to include questions. Thank you for pointing that out to me @MarcB. I forgot on the StackOverflow tour it says "This site is all about getting answers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing a `join`?  For the data you've provided and the description, I think the following is pretty much what you want:

```
select t1.ShipmentNumber, max(t1.COST) + coalesce(sum(t2.COST)), t1.trackingnumber
from t t1 left join
     t t2
     on t2.trackingnumber like t1.ShipmentNumber + 'B%'
where t1.trackingnumber not like '%B%'
group by t1.ShipmentNumber, t1.trackingnumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following select will get you all rows where the tracking number contains a "B":

```
Select * From tableName Where TrackingNumber Like '%B%' And TrackingNumber NOT Like 'B%'
```

Comment: As part of the select, use charindex, as suggested above to extract just the portion you want into a new field. That should get you started...